# expression 'net.sniff.http.response' did not match any filter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wifi

I have a problem!

I recently downloaded a virtual box on my windows 11 to use Linux (ubuntu 22.04 "I downloaded by fault instead of kali :>") beside it.

I installed **Bettercap** to know what is going on my network and for practice also :).

I started with these commands:

1. `sudo bettercap`
2. `net.probe on`
3. `net.show`
4. `set arp.spoof.targets 192.168.8.11`
5. `arp.spoof on`
6. `net.sniff on`

What i need from those steps is to see what the user who connect too my network browse.

what happened is this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nsDw.png)

It shows only `net.sniff.mdns`  which is not what i needed. i only need for `net.sniff.dns or net.sniff.https` to show the links were visited.

I tried this `events.include net.sniff.http.response` but it gives me this error.

I hope you got my problem.

**Note**: First time i run those it didn't work but in the second time it works without doing anything.

I tried to search to get the answer but there is no one mention this problem